# How do I remove the "unlicensed trial version" message on a TMS Web Core project?

Tags: delphi, tms, tms-web-core

When creating a TMS Web Core Delphi Project and running it, I get the following popup message:

> Application created with an unlicensed trial version of software

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core - Application created with an unlicensed trial version of software]

Is there a way to remove this message to make testing a bit easier?

I tried looking for a place to remove the message, but couldn't find it. I also tried looking into the `C:\Users\User\Local\AppData\tmssoftware\trial` folder for licensing files, but could not find the licensing files.

Is it possible to remove this for testing purposes without needing to buy TMS Web Core?

Comment: Maybe add the screenshot into the question instead of linking to it.

Comment: You can presumably remove the message by paying for a license and using the licensed version to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you're using TMS Web Core for creating anything commercially, then I would recommend [buying TMS Web Core](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmswebcore.asp#buy) instead of removing the "Application created with an unlicensed trial version of software" message.

But for educational reasons, here's how you could remove it.

---

TMS Web Core simply compiles all of your Delphi (Pascal) code down to normal HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

In your project's folder, you'll see a different folder named `TMSWeb`. All of your output files are in there. Find the main `.js` file in there. The main `.js` file will have the same name as your Delphi project.

Somewhere in that file is the following lines of code:

```js
this.TriggerNotification = function () {
  if (this.FNotifyCount === 0) {
    alert('Application created with an unlicensed trial version of software');
  };
  this.FNotifyCount += 1;
};
```

You can simply delete (remove) the following line:

```js
alert('Application created with an unlicensed trial version of software');
```

And then the trial message won't appear.

Comment: Good answer, if you change *for educational reasons* to *for piracy purposes*.